# How to remove a class when its element is not in view?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll, toggle

In plain js I want to remove a class when the user scroll down from it. (basically toggle when in view it appear when it is not in view it disappear)
I have to code to add the class when scrolled in view:

```
const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, appearOnScroll){
    entries.forEach(entry =>{
        if(!entry.isIntersecting){
            return;
        }else{
            entry.target.classList.add("appear");
            appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
    })
}, appearOptions);

faders.forEach(fader =>{
    appearOnScroll.observe(fader)
})
```

How can I remove the class when you scroll out?

Comment: `entry.target.classList.remove("appear")`

Comment: @Konrad I got that muchxd but where should i put it so its not instantly removes it? only when i scroll out of view?

Comment: Are you using `defer` when importing the script?

Comment: @TermoPollo  <script src="./index.js"></script> is my inport to index.html